# Proof of the second Bianchi identity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, geometry

Suppose $\omega$ is a connection one-form, and the curvature tensor is defined as

$$R^a_{~~b} = d\omega^a_{~~b} + \omega^a_{~~c}\wedge \omega^c_{~~b}~,$$

where the latin indices refer to the fact that $\omega$ is a matrix valued one-form. I want to show that $DR^a_{~~b} = 0$ where $D$ is the covariant exterior derivative. Explicitly computing this out, one obtains

\begin{align}
DR^a_{~~b} &= dR^a_{~~b} + \omega^a_{~~c}\wedge R^{c}_{~~b} + \omega^c_{~~b}\wedge R^{a}_{~~c} \\
&= d\left(d\omega^a_{~~b} + \omega^a_{~~c}\wedge \omega^c_{~~b}\right) + \omega^a_{~~c}\wedge \left(d\omega^c_{~~b} + \omega^c_{~~d}\wedge \omega^d_{~~b}\right) + \omega^c_{~~b}\wedge\left(d\omega^a_{~~c} + \omega^a_{~~d}\wedge \omega^d_{~~c}\right) \\ 
&= d^2\omega^a_{~~b} + d\omega^a_{~~c}\wedge \omega^c_{~~b} - \omega^a_{~~c}\wedge d\omega^c_{~~b} + \left(\omega^a_{~~c}\wedge d\omega^c_{~~b}\right) + \left(\omega^a_{~~c}\wedge \omega^c_{~~d}\wedge \omega^d_{~~b}\right) + \left(\omega^c_{~~b}\wedge d\omega^a_{~~c}\right) + \left(\omega^c_{~~b}\wedge \omega^a_{~~d}\wedge \omega^d_{~~c}\right) \\ 
&= \left(\omega^a_{~~c}\wedge \omega^c_{~~d}\wedge \omega^d_{~~b}\right)+ \left(\omega^c_{~~b}\wedge \omega^a_{~~d}\wedge \omega^d_{~~c}\right) \\ 
&= 2\left(\omega^a_{~~c}\wedge \omega^c_{~~d}\wedge \omega^d_{~~b}\right)
\end{align}

where the last equality is obtained by renaming the dummy indices in the second term. However, I don't see why the final wedge product must be identically zero so I suspect I must have gone wrong somewhere and the two terms must cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(E,\pi,M)$ be a vector bundle with a connection $\nabla$ on it. Let $R$ be the curvature, which is an $\text{End}(E)$-valued 2-form on $M$. Let $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ be a local frame for $E$ over an open set $U\subset M$, and $\{\epsilon^1,\dots,\epsilon^n\}$ its dual. Then, using the isomorphism $\text{End}(E)\cong E^*\otimes E$, we can identify $R$ with an $E^*\otimes E$-valued $2$-form on $M$, and with respect to the above frames, we can write
\begin{align}
R&=R^a_{\,b}\cdot\,\epsilon^b\otimes e_a,
\end{align}
where now each $R^a_{\,b}$ is a usual 2-form on the open set $U\subset M$. By taking the exterior covariant derivative of both sides (note that we need to use the induced connection on $E^*\otimes E$ which is defined such that the Leibniz rule holds):
\begin{align}
D_{E\otimes E^*}R&=(dR^a_{\,b})\cdot \epsilon^b\otimes e_a+ (-1)^2R^{a}_{\,b}\wedge D_{E^*\otimes E}(\epsilon^b\otimes e_a)\\
&=(dR^a_{\,b})\cdot \epsilon^b\otimes e_a+ R^a_{\,b}\wedge \left[(D_{E^*}\epsilon^b)\otimes e_a+\epsilon^b\otimes (D_Ee_a)\right].
\end{align}
Now, you use the fact that by definition, $D_E(e_a)=\omega^c_{\,a}\,\cdot e_c$. From here, by differentiating the equation $\delta^b_{\,a}=\epsilon^b(e_a)$ and using the definition of the connections on $E$ and $E^*$, you immediately find that $D_{E^*}(\epsilon^b)=-\omega^b_{\,c}\cdot\epsilon^c$. This is an important minus sign. Plugging this and shuffling the indices, you get
\begin{align}
D_{E^*\otimes E}R&=\left(dR^a_{\,b}-R^a_{\,c}\wedge\omega^c_{\,b}+R^c_{\,b}\wedge \omega^{a}_{\,c}\right)\cdot\epsilon^b\otimes e_a.
\end{align}
Hence, $(DR)^a_{\,b}=dR^{a}_{\,b}-R^{a}_{\,c}\wedge \omega^c_{\,b}+R^{c}_{\,b}\wedge \omega^a_{\,c}$. I personally prefer to swap the order of the wedge on the third term (note we have a 2-form and a 1-form, so when we swap, we produce a sign of $(-1)^{(2)(1)}=1$, so no sign change), which yields
\begin{align}
(DR)^{a}_{\,b}&=dR^a_{\,b}+\omega^a_{\,c}\wedge R^c_{\,b}-R^a_{\,c}\wedge \omega^c_{\,b},
\end{align}
which you can think of as $dR-\omega\wedge_{[\cdot,\cdot]}R$ (wedge product with respect to the matrix commutator). Anyway, at this stage, it’s just aesthetics.

I took a look at the book you referenced, and that is just wrong; the minus sign **is** missing.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Although I have not come to bundles yet, I think I understand what you are saying.  So essentially the minus sign comes from the earlier requirement of $E_ae^b = \delta_a^b$.

Comment: @newtothis exactly

Answer (score 3):

The covariant exterior derivative in question is $$ DR^a_{\ b}=\mathrm{d}\omega^{a}_{\ b}+\omega^{a}_{\ c}\wedge R^{c}_{\ b}-\omega^{c}_{\ b}\wedge R^{a}_{\ c}, $$ so you got a sign error there. Once you account for this sign, things will come out nicely.

---

But for fun and giggles, here is a more abstract proof. If $\lambda^a$ is any vector-valued $k$-form, we have $$ D^2\lambda^a=R^a_{\ b}\wedge\lambda^b. $$ Now evaluate $D^3\lambda^a$ two different ways: $$ D^3\lambda^a=D(D^2\lambda^a)=D(R^a_{\ b}\wedge\lambda^b)=DR^a_{\ b}\wedge\lambda^b+R^a_{\ b}\wedge D\lambda^b, $$but also $$ D^3\lambda^a=D^2(D\lambda^a)=R^a_{\ b}\wedge D\lambda^b. $$ Substracting the two, we get $$ 0=DR^a_{\ b}\wedge\lambda^b. $$ This is true for any vector-valued $k$-form $\lambda^a$, including the case when $\lambda^a=X^a$ is a vector-valued $0$-form, i.e. a vector field, giving $$ DR^a_{\ b}X^b=0 $$valid for any vector field. Thus, $DR^a_{\ b}=0$.

Comment: Is the covariant exterior derivative defined in this way? 
I am following the book "Lectures on Advanced Mathematical Methods for Physicists" by Sunil Mukhi (https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789814299749_others01) where this derivative is defined with the plus sign.

Comment: @newtothis I can't access the book but upper and lower indices get connection terms with different signs. That's the same for ordinary covariant differentiation.

Comment: @newtothis the book you mentioned definitely has a typo. In my “answer” I gave an explanation of where that minus sign comes from.